# How to migrate mongodb data from mongodb 5.0 to mongodb 6.0 database

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, digital-ocean

I need to migrate data from a mongodb 5.0 database replica set to digital ocean mongodb 6.0 replica set. What is the best approach to do this? Do I need to upgrade the current server to mongodb 6.0 first before migrating the data to the new server?

Comment: See [Upgrade a Replica Set to 6.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/release-notes/6.0-upgrade-replica-set/)

Comment: Hi wernfried, thanks for the comment but the doc only explain how to upgrade the database server from 5.0 to 6.0 but it never stated how to migrate data from server 5.0 to another server which is mongodb 6.0

Comment: Use [MongoDB Database Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/). You can export the data with `mongodump` and import to new database with `mongorestore`

Comment: is the mongodb 5.0 data backup with mongodump and restore with mongorestore automatically make the data compatible with mongodb 6.0?

Comment: I think it is compatible, see [MongoDB Server Compatibility](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#mongodb-server-compatibility). Be aware, the versioning of the database tools are independent from MongoDB.